# Spring WebTestClient request and response validation

Tags: spring-webflux, openapi

Based on what has been done by [Atlassian](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/swagger-request-validator-spring-web-client/src/main/java/com/atlassian/oai/validator/springweb/client/OpenApiValidationClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java) to validate a request and response against an OpenAPI specification, I'd like to adapt this logic to WebTestClient.
My approach is to configure the WebTestClient with a specific filter, however I cannot find an easy way to access the request body through an *ExchangeFilterFunction*.